# Spring aop @AfterThrowing fail when method annotate @Transaction

Tags: spring, aop, spring-transactions

i want to get Exception on method through Spring aop, and the method annotate a `@Transactional` annotation.
when i insert a record that is in the DB, it would be throw Exception, but aop can't catch the 
Exception. Is double proxy problem ? outer proxy is Transaction, inner proxy is aop ? 
any idea idea ?

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean doInsert(Object domainObject) throws Exception {
    boolean success = false;

    if (beforeInsert(domainObject)) {
        if (insert(domainObject)) {
            success = afterInsert(domainObject);

        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

---

```
@AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* com.digiwin.newb2.patterns.Nb2ProgramService.doInsert(..))", argNames="retVal", throwing="retVal")
public void doInsertThrowException(Exception ex) {

    int index = 0;

}
```

---

when insert a record throw exception but not trigger aop...

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
at        org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:143)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:680)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:562)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
at com.digiwin.newb2.test.ProgramSingle02TestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8eea6179.doInsert(<generated>)
at com.digiwin.newb2.patterns.SysSingle01Controller.saveActionCore(SysSingle01Controller.java:486)
at com.digiwin.newb2.patterns.SysSingle02Controller.saveActionCore(SysSingle02Controller.java:870)
at com.digiwin.newb2.patterns.SysSingle01Controller.saveAction(SysSingle01Controller.java:410)
```

Comment: I doubt that your aspect will even work.. Your argument is named `ex` not `retVal`. So your aspect is already flawed.

Comment: @M.Deinum it can work by other method without annotate Transactional, i already test :)

Comment: Then I doubt the code you posted is the code you are actually using. However the ordering of the aspect shouldn't matter as exceptions propagate to the caller of the `doInsert` method. Make sure that the aspect is in the correct context (the same as the bean is defined in).

Comment: @M.Deinum i post the stacktrace, at com.digiwin.newb2.test.ProgramSingle02TestService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8eea6179.doInsert, it seem the context is correct

Comment: That doesn't tell you anything, it only tells you that there is a proxy, judging from the stacktrace only transactions are applied. Do you have a `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` and make sure that that is in the same context as `<tx:annotation-driven />`

Comment: @M.Deinum, It is configuration issue, <tx:annotation-driven order="500"> in applicationContext.xml and the Aspectj class annoate order that must less than above.